# script in document.ready is not work when first time page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nopcommerce

in my project when first time page load that time my code in document.ready is not execute but after second time load it work perfect. why it happen i can't understand about it.

Now what can i do. I dont know the way to solve this problem.

[image]

**Get error**

Reload the page to get source for: url of jquery

Comment: Perhaps you could show your actual code, and check the console for JS errors?

Comment: Did you really write it as `Document.Ready` or `document.ready`?

Comment: $(document).ready(function()  i have used in my project

Comment: From your first `image` I can make it that its fetching it from **`cache`** [guessing].. Try clearing cache once and check if it hits `document.ready` on page load?

Comment: i try this one but still its not working

Comment: please provide your sample code so developers can understand, otherwise with console log can't get idea about it

Comment: now i add my sample code data into my question.